# npm start does not work after npx create-next-app

Tags: macos, next.js, node-modules, npx, npm-start

I was trying to start with next.js and started a new project.
I am facing issue with `npm start` after doing `npx create-next-app`.

It gives the following error on `npm start`

```
> coursepage@0.1.0 start
> next start

sh: next: command not found
```

I have tried deleting node-modules and reinstalling using `npm install`.

On `npm list next`, it even gives

```
coursepage@0.1.0 /Users/<path/to/folder>/coursepage
└── next@13.4.12
```

I am on node `v18.16.1`.
I even deleted and reinstall node using brew.

Any ideas??

Comment: Try this command "npm install -g next"

Comment: I tried it and it solved the issue. But I am not sure if it is safe to use global next.js.
Also I was getting `- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` after running `npm run dev`

Comment: Awesome, and it's totally safe to use global next